# Bootstrap 3 Carousel has horizontal grey bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

this is the website i am building http://vps1-isosoft.webserve.gr/greekorama/index.php?content=home (it's in greek-language just ignore the words, Αρχική Σελίδα = Home Page, etc) and i am facing a problem here, i tried to solve it but i couldn't.

Here it is. There is a horizontal grey bar at the bottom of my Carousel. And i don't know how to fix it. I tried through css to edit the element `.carousel-control` but it doesn't seem to help.

here is my code for carousel `

```
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <img src="images/assets.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <img src="images/falakro8.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <img src="images/ouranoupoli3.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>`
```

There are some minor problems/bug in the site but it can deal with them. Don't mind them.

Comment: This question would be impossible to even understand if you change your website. You should put a reproducing example in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They gray bar at the bottom is caused by a general box-shadow css rule on your `img`elements:

```
img {
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   /*START PROBLEM*/
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc; 
   -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc; 
   /*END PROBLEM*/
}
```

If you disable those box-shadow rules, the grey bar disappears.

However, this also affects your `.img-circle` elements, so either apply the shadow only to the `.img-circle` class or override the box-shadow values for the `.homeCarousel img` (and disable the background-image for the `.carousel-control` elements, this also casts a shadow)

Comment: i did what you said, and the problem is 50% solved. but the grey bar is still there, at the bottom of my carousel. the problem is not on the box rules specifically. i'm still thankfull for your answer

Comment: Did you also disable the background images for the .carousel-control elements?

Comment: No i didn't but i did it now. And it worked. Thank you friend. I appreciate your help :)